# How to get terms by hierarchy level?

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, levels, taxonomy-terms

### What I have

1. I have a custom taxonomy called **properties.**
2. The taxonomy type is hierarchical.
3. The structure is:

```
Properties
  -- Property 1
    -- Property 1.1
      -- Property 1.1.1
           and so on ...
 -- Property 2
   -- Property 2.1
     -- Property 2.1.1
        ...
   -- Property 2.2
      -- Property 2.2.1
         ...
 -- Property 3
    ...
```

### The result I need to achieve

To get terms by levels.
F.e:

1. If **Level = 1**. Expected results

```
 Property 1
 Property 2
 Property 3
 ...
```

2. If **Level = 2**. Expected results

```
 Property 1.1
 Property 2.1
 Property 2.2
 Property 3.1
 ...
```

3. If **Level = 3**. Expected results

```
 Property 1.1.1
 Property 2.1.1
 Property 2.2.1
 Property 3.1.1
 ...
```

Using `get_terms` function doesn't allow to get terms by level.
I need some function or to know the way to get terms by level.

```
function get_terms_by_level($level) {
   /// ... ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Following your comments. If you know which are which, you can always use `get_term_children()`.

```
$heirs = get_term_children( 'your-term-slug', $taxonomy );
var_dump( $heirs );
foreach ( $heirs as $key => $value ) {
    echo $value;
};
```

---

To achieve that kind of structure you need to think of your query like a [matryoshka doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

You query your first level taxonomy terms, then move on to querying your second level while being in the first level, and so on, and so on...

```
<?php $taxonomy = 'custom-taxonomy-slug';
$first_level_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, [
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'title_li' => '',
] );
if ( $first_level_terms ) {
    foreach ( $first_level_terms as $first_level_term ) {
        $second_level_terms = get_terms( [
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'child_of' => $first_level_term->term_id,
            'parent' => $first_level_term->term_id,
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'title_li' => '',
        ] );
        if ( $second_level_terms ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ( $second_level_terms as $second_level_term ) {
                echo '<li>' . $second_level_term->slug . '</li>';
            };
            echo '</ul>';
        };
    };
}; ?>
```